# How to calculate Nth business date using Calculated column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

Find the Nth business day from today. Here, I need to find the 13th business day from today using calculated column of SharePoint.

I want to exclude Saturday and Sunday because I only need 13 working days. 
Currently I keep on getting 10, here's my current formula:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(Today)>1,IF(WEEKDAY(Today)<5,Today+14,Today+16),Today+15)
```

Comment: Where does your Today column come from? And how is it filled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below formula to find the 13th business day,

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(Today)=1,Today+17,IF(WEEKDAY(Today)=2,Today+16,IF(WEEKDAY(Today)=3,Today+16,IF(WEEKDAY(Today)=4,Today+16,Today+18))))
```

The above equation has been formulated including today also as one business day, example if Today is 06/06/2016 then 13th business day is 22/06/2016. If you want the formula excluding today, use the below one

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(Today)=1,Today+18,IF(WEEKDAY(Today)=2,Today+17,IF(WEEKDAY(Today)=3,Today+17,IF(WEEKDAY(Today)=4,Today+17,Today+19))))
```

**The base formula is,**

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(Today)=1,Today+(N+4),IF(WEEKDAY(Today)=2,Today+(N+3),IF(WEEKDAY(Today)=3,Today+(N+3),IF(WEEKDAY(Today)=4,Today+(N+3),Today+(N+5)))))
```

*Where N is COUNT OF BUSINESS DAYS*

Comment: Doesn't ``Today`` produce an error: http://i.imgur.com/snpaulZ.jpg

Comment: I have created a date time column named today and set its default value to today

Comment: hi guys sorry i wasn't able to get back right away. thanks for all the help! the code works! :)